# Why does a command have just a { get; set } which other parameters have a backing field specified?

Tags: c#, .net

Given this code:

```
    public ICommand CopyCmd { get; set; }

    string _fullName;

    public string FullName
    {
        get => _fullName;
        set => SetProperty(ref _fullName, value);
    }
```

Why is it that the command can be handled with a { get; set; } but the name required my developer to add a backing field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `CopyCmd` property in the question is an [**auto-implemented** property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/auto-implemented-properties). It is equivalent to this code:

```
private ICommand _CopyCmd;
public ICommand CopyCmd {
   get { return CopyCmd;}
   set { _CopyCmd = value;  }
}
```

In fact, the only difference between the above and what the compiler really does is the actual produced IL uses a different name than `_CopyCmd` which is not legal for C#, such that you can't accidently create a name in your own code which will conflict with the backing field.

The `FullName` property, though, does more work in the `set` block. You can do *anything* in a `set` block, but as soon you do more than assign the value to a backing field you can't use an auto-implemented property anymore.

In this case, the code also calls the `SetProperty()` method, which matches a convention typically associated with [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged?view=net-5.0). This makes it easy to have an event you can subscribe to which is raised any time this property changes.

Answer (score 2):

Because of `SetProperty` method. It looks like kind of [implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1315621/implementing-inotifypropertychanged-does-a-better-way-exist).
So, your view need to know when `FullName` value is changed.